# Перезапуск консольного приложения

Tags: c, консоль

Пишу консольное приложение, которое считает ряд разложения функции. Есть требование, чтобы приложение спрашивало у пользователя "Попробовать ещё раз? y/n", и при вводе `y` перезапускалось.

Я реализую это так:

```
    wchar_t tryAgain;
do {
    puts("\n Wanna try again? (y/n)");
    fflush(stdin);
} while(scanf("%c", &tryAgain) !=1);

switch(tryAgain) {
    case 'y':   system(argv[0]);    break;
    case 'n':   system("exit"); break;
    default:    system("exit");
}
```

Но возникает проблема: таким образом создаётся новая копия программы в памяти:

[image: Вот что получается]

Это как бы не совсем рационально, и поэтому возникает вопрос: можно ли именно перезапускать приложение, а не создавать новый экземпляр в памяти?

Comment: Да, конечно, можно. Посмотрите `man execv` (в винде еще есть какой-то свой аналог)

Comment: Непонятно, с какой целью приложение надо завершать, и почему не реализовать внутри приложения цикл?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оберните основной код в цикл. При ответе нет - выход из цикла и как следствие завершение приложение. При ответе да - цикл просто повторяется, как результат выполнение постоянно происходит в одном процессе. Главное не забудьте инициализировать значения переменных.

Answer (score 1):

```
wchar_t tryAgain;

while(1) {

    //your code here

    puts("\n Wanna try again? (y/n)");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &tryAgain);
    if(tryAgain=='n' || tryAgain=='N') {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тебе в этом случае посоветовал бы использовать goto, но их использование - плохой стиль программирования. Поэтому лучше используй циклы. Вот пример, аналогичный твоему вопросу:

```
wchar_t tryAgain;
for(;;){
   for(;;){
      //Ваш код тут
      printf("\n Wanna try again? (y/n)");
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%c", &tryAgain);
      if(tryAgain=='n' || tryAgain=='N') break;
   }
}
```

Опытный программист всегда знает, как заменить goto в своей программе